# JRE-9 deprecate browser plug-in - Can web start (JNLP) run directly in JRE-9?

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp, java-9

As Java claimed JRE-9 would deprecate support of Java Browser Plug-in, I tried to disable "Browser plug-in' it Java Control Panel. (like figure below)

Then all existing web start JNLP can't run anymore.

like example in: [Deploying a Java Web Start Application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/deploying.html)

Would anyone has idea how to handle your applet/web start under JRE 9 / Java9?

For more information please see the below screenshot of disable java browser plug-in.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Java Web Start has always (since its inception) supported free floating (outside the browser) frames (e.g. `java.awt.Frame` & `javax.swing.JFrame`) ***&*** applets (e.g `java.applet.Applet` & `javax.swing.JApplet`).

That should still work, though it was always the case that free floating applets could not access the `JSObject` or (thereby) interact with any web page.

Comment: @hv2 is there anything missing from this answer hv2? It looks like it is a good one, so I think it deserves some attention from you. Without it is impossible to see if it is correct.